# Convert array of objects to object of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, mongoose

What I have:

```
[{title: hi}, {title: ha}, {title: ho}]
```

What I want:

```
{title: hi}, {title: ha}, {title: ho}
```

This is because, when I try to add the array to a database, like:

```
"$push" : { "paises" : array}
```

, it will be:

[Array of objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFur5.png)

But I want this:

[Object of objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaAs1.png)

Comment: not sure what your asking for here, your "what I want" is an array of objects.

Comment: Sure, what I need is to 'destroy' the array '[{title: hi}, {title: ha}, {title: ho}]', else I will have two arrays of objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution:

```
var array = [{title: 'hi'}, {title: 'ha'}, {title: 'ho'}];

var object = {};

var arrayToObject = function(array, object){
  array.forEach(function(element, index){
    object[index] = element;
  })
  console.log(object);
}

arrayToObject(array, object);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2r903tdh/

Answer (score 0):

```
{title: hi}, {title: ha}, {title: ho}
```

This is not object of objects. These are just objects.

If what you want is a way to handle each object one by one and insert them into your database you could do something like this.

```
[{title: hi}, {title: ha}, {title: ho}].forEach(function(obj){
  //do something with object
});
```

Comment: Yes, I thought in it, but is it possible to update one time the database, and not n times for each object?

Comment: How are you inserting them? db.paises.insert() ?

Comment: Just with "$push" : { "paises" : array}

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ES6 you can use [`spread`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) operator.

`...[{title: hi}, {title: ha}, {title: ho}]` = `{title: hi}, {title: ha}, {title: ho}`